# How to display different sub-forms depending on a form selection?

Tags: html, forms

I'm working on a web interface that adds information to a database based on form submissions.

Let's say we want to add "Vehicles" to our database.
A vehicle has three fields: Type, Make, and Color.

Although all three fields are visible, when we select cars we only want to see Make and Color options that pertain to cars.  The same goes for Motorcycles.

How can I make display options in the latter two fields dependent upon the parent selection?

I've looked into making individual forms for each group of options, class grouping them, and displaying based on that, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I don't believe the CSS can be dynamically modified.

```
<form class="Tester" action = "/submitSelection.php" method = "post">
    <select size = "1">
        <option value = "Cars">Cars</option>
             <!--if Cars selected, makes are "Toyota" "Dodge"-->
    <option value = "Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
             <!--if Motorcycles selected, makes are "Yamaha" "Harley"-->
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to hide, or modify, latter options based on this above form, but have no method to do so.

Comment: use a where in your query?

Comment: @xmaster I could have been more clear by adding more code, I would like the Makes to be a visible form as well, but only display motorcycle makes when this form selects Motorcycle, and the same for the case that Car is selected